# ArrayList emptying itself?

Tags: java, arraylist, awt, mouselistener

Follow the path of eventList please.  While it stores the proper objects as it's supposed to initially, it empties itself as soon as it enters MouseClicked().  There is a driver used to run initialize() in another class.  I just can't seem to get eventList to hold its information.

```
public class Adventure_Chapter1 implements MouseListener
{
boolean success = true;
ArrayList<StoryEvent> eventList = new ArrayList<StoryEvent>();

public void initiliaze() throws FontFormatException, IOException
{
load();     // loads StoryEvents
play(0);
System.out.println("Init() eventList size: " + eventList.size());
}

private void load()
{
    int x = 0;
    switch(x)
    {
    case 0:
    StoryEvent txt0 = new StoryEvent(parameters);
    eventList.add(txt0); 
    case 1:
    StoryEvent assassinStart = new StoryEvent(parameters);
    eventList.add(assassinStart);
}
}

public void updatePlayer()
{
    System.out.println("Player Updated ");
}

public void play(int c)                                 // to be implemented
{
    storyLineDisplay.setText("testing");
    System.out.println("Play() eventList size:" + eventList.size());
    //int c would typically change my buttons' options next to them. but for now it
      is irrelevant.
 }

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    if (e.getSource().equals(buttonOne));
    {
        if (success == true)
        {
            updatePlayer();
            System.out.println("MouseClicked eventList size: " + eventList.size());
            play(1);
        }
        else
        {
            updatePlayer();
            currentCharacter.add(eventList.get(choice));
            choice = currentCharacter.get(currentCharacter.size() -1).getFail1();
            play(1);
        }
    }

}
```

Output is here:

```
Play() eventList size:2
Init() eventList size: 2
Player Updated 
MouseClicked eventList size: 0
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at Adventure_Chapter1.mouseClicked(Adventure_Chapter1.java:277)
     insert further lines of errors here.
```

Comment: Please apply proper formatting!

Comment: Before we answer this, you want to do yourself a favour and remove code that does not contribute to your problem until you have a minimal code base that still shows the problem. While you're doing this, you're almost guaranteed to discover the problem.

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with the problem, but there is an extra semicolon on this line in `mouseClicked`: `if (e.getSource().equals(buttonOne));` that needs to be removed.

Comment: I'd advise you to run your code in debug mode and add a watch on `eventList`. The code you presented looks fine to me. Probably you override your list somewhere else.

Comment: Edited to remove more code.  Whatever is there now affects eventList or is needed to follow the output.

Comment: There's possibly a bug in your `switch`: `case 0` adds *two* items to the list because there's no `break`

Comment: Bohemian, I hadn't even noticed that. I must've overlooked that a thousand times. I'll try fixing it so that it break after each, and it would definitely save me some time elsewhere in the program.  Edit: I may be able to remove that switch case entirly, or add a lot to it. Either way should work for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
if (e.getSource().equals(buttonOne));
{
    if (success == true)
    {
        updatePlayer();
        System.out.println("MouseClicked eventList size: " + eventList.size());
        play(choice);
    }
    else
    {
        updatePlayer();
        currentCharacter.add(eventList.get(choice));
        choice = currentCharacter.get(currentCharacter.size() -1).getFail1();

    }
}
}
```

but what is "choice" ?

Comment: choice is currently 1, my apologies.  That's not actually relevant to my issue.  I use it to change the JTextAreas in my GUI. It is defined in the code, it was just edited out.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should break your switch statements.
2. `if (success == true)`

   can be replaced by

   ```
   if (success)
   ```
3. `if (e.getSource().equals(buttonOne));`

   must be replaced by

   ```
   if (e.getSource().equals(buttonOne))
   ```
4. put all of the involved code if you want help with debugging, we are not mind readers and guessers. Obviously there are missing code.

**Edited**

Can we see the code for StoryEvent. Are you touching the `evenList` list there
        ? Otherwise I don't understand how you get two elements in your
        evenList, to begin with.